# Proper Non-blocking recv /select for TCP server

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, recv, tcpserver

I have to write a code that allows non-blocking recv (along with non-blocking accept)
The following is what I got so far:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('', int(PortEntry_Page2_Text))
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.setblocking(0)
sock.settimeout(1)
sock.listen(1)
EnterToTerminal2("Listening to port "+str(PortEntry_Page2_Text)+"..")
EnterToTerminal2("Waiting for a connection. Press STOP to cancel.")
connected = 0
while (StopButtonStatePage2 == 0 and connected == 0):
    try:
        connection, client_address = sock.accept()
        EnterToTerminal2("Connection from "+ str(client_address)+"..")
        connected = 1
    except Exception as inst:
        template = "An exception of type {0} occured. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
        message = template.format(type(inst).__name__,inst.args)
        print message
    finally:
        if (connected == 0):
            EnterToTerminal2("No client connected..")
    StopButtonStatePage2 = GetStopButtonStatePage2()
########################################### 
StopButtonStatePage2 = 0
sock.setblocking(0) ##?
print "xx0 "+str(connected)+" "+str(StopButtonStatePage2)
while (connected == 1 and StopButtonStatePage2 == 0):
    a = select.select([sock], [], [], 1) # steelkiwi.com/blog/working-tcp-sockets
    if a[0]:##?
        data = sock.recv(64) # or connection.recv ??
        EnterToTerminal2("Data recv: "+str(data))
    StopButtonStatePage2 = GetStopButtonStatePage2()
```

Until sock.recv part, it works as expected.  Now, the problem is that with the select approach, it does not enter the a[0] condition at all, even though I send stuff from client. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to make recv part non-blocking/or with timeout so that I can stop its operation with a button, whenever I want.
Any help is appreaciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I strongly recommend using blocking sockets, but having multiple threads - one which does the work, one which handles the program lifetime.

Comment: You are receiving on the wrong socket. `sock` is the listener (maybe call it `listen_socket`) and `connection` is the client socket (maybe call it `client_socket`).

Comment: Ahh thanks a million. What a mistake. Would you like to post so I can accept your answer?